# jQuery UI progress bar did not work in Loop in IE 11 and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-progressbar

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery-ui is 1.10.4. My code works perfectly in FireFox. My code for jQuery as below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#progressbar").show();
      $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: false
      });
      progress(10, "Initialize");
      /* If Season Year is zero than throw error */
      if (seasonYearCount == 0) {
        progress(0, Res.errGeneratingSchedule);
        return;
      }
      if (seasonYearMonthCount == 0) {
        $("#lbErrorMsg").text(Res.errGeneratingSchedule);
        progress(0, Res.errGeneratingSchedule);
        alert(Res.setupSeasonYearMonth);
        return;
      }
      if (productYearCount == 0) {
       progress(15, "Adding Products");
      }

      $.each(productArray, function (index, product) {
        progress(17, "Adding Complaints");
      });
      _days = daysInMonth($("#dpMonth").val(), $("#dpYear").val());
      for (var pWC = 0; pWC < _productWithComplaint.length; pWC++) {
        progress(pWC + 17, "Making Plan");
      //console.dir(_plan);
      progress(100, "Complete");
      $("#progressbar").hide();
});

function progress(value, text) {
$("#progressbar").progressbar("value", value);
var currValue = $("#progressbar").progressbar("value");

$("#lbMessage").text(text + " - " + currValue + "%");
 }
```

This is my HTML Code

```
<div id="progressbar" style="display:none;">
 <div id='lbMessage'>Loading...</div>
</div>
```

can somebody help on this...

fiddle for the source code http://jsfiddle.net/milindsaraswala/2CFxZ/

Comment: "Not working" is not a description of a problem. What does it do instead of the expected result? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Did you debug your code using "Developer Tools" (F12 shortcut) included on IE browser?

Comment: No error in the console. As i told you i get expected result firefox but not in internet explorer, in IE i cannot see progressbar at all

Comment: As per requested I added jsfiddle in question edited

Comment: @Milind: Your fiddle has an error: `createCalendar is not defined`

Comment: Hi removed that function, now it is not showing progressbar at all

Comment: I removed createCalendar function, but now progress bar not showing at all.

Comment: @Cory any idea for my issue

Comment: @Milind: Your code works fine. It runs so fast that you don't see the progress from 0 to 100. The only problem in your fiddle is that you show the progress bar right away and hide it immediately after the code has run. All of this takes just a few milliseconds. Remove the `hide()` call at the end if you want to still see the progress bar.

Comment: @Cory other code running in for loop but remove it in fiddle and i can see progress bar in firefox but not in chrome n IE

Comment: I've been looking at your code in Chrome and it is doing exactly what I would expect it to (as you've written it). Maybe you have an error somewhere else in some code you're not showing us, or your code is technically working in Chrome/IE and broken in Firefox.

Comment: Ok lets say, I remove hide code line for progress bar. Then it is not showing at all progress. It is just showing complete at the end. How can I show progress in my progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's a syntax error. You haven't closed the brace on your for-loop:

```
      for (var pWC = 0; pWC < _productWithComplaint.length; pWC++) {
        progress(pWC + 17, "Making Plan");

      } // <== MISSING THIS

      //console.dir(_plan);
      progress(100, "Complete");
      $("#progressbar").hide();
});
```

Always check the console for JS errors.

**EDIT**

The code in your fiddle works fine. It runs so fast that you don't see the progress from 0 to 100. You don't see the progress bar at all really because you hide it right after the rest of the code has finished, which takes just a few milliseconds.

Comment: It may be i make mistake in cut-copy-paste in question but i m not getting error in console.

Comment: Could you put together an example at jsfiddle or jsbin or then edit your question to include a link to an example that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: As per requested I added jsfiddle in question edited